# Relationships between $\operatorname{LL}(k)$, $\operatorname{LR}(k)$ language sets

Tags: formal-languages, parsing

I'm trying to establish (through constructing a [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram)) the subset relationship between the classes of languages that can be parsed by $\operatorname{LL}(k)$ and $\operatorname{LR}(k)$ parsers. My guess is that

> $$\operatorname{LL}(0) \subset \operatorname{LL}(1) \subset \operatorname{LL}(2) \subset \dots  \\ \cap \phantom{\operatorname{LL}(0)} \cap \phantom{\operatorname{LL}(0)} \cap \phantom{\operatorname{LL}(0)}\\
> \operatorname{LR}(0) \subset \operatorname{LR}(1) \subset \operatorname{LR}(2) \subset \dots$$

but I'm not sure if that's correct. Can someone verify this?

To further understand the relationship, I'd also like to find out:

- Am I correct in thinking $\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty \operatorname{LR}(k) =$ [$\mathrm{DCFL}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_language)?
- What about $\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty \operatorname{LL}(k)$?
- Where would the class of [$\operatorname{LL}(^*\!)$](http://www.antlr.org/papers/LL-star-PLDI11.pdf)-parsable languages fit into this diagram?

Comment: Your question is answered here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43. Your diagram becomes true when you replace $LR(n+1) ⊂ LR(n+2)$ with $LR(n+1) = LR(n+2)$ for every $n$